# Problema con http y node js, ECONNREFUSED al hacer una petición post a servidor con express

Tags: nodejs, express, post, http

estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de hacer post a un servidor node con express. Estoy desarrollando una librería que hará peticiones post usando el módulo http de node, pero a la hora de probarlo en mi ordenador con un servidor de prueba local, me sale el siguiente error

```
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3004
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3004
}
```

La verdad no tengo idea de que puede ser, ya que he investigado el error y siempre sugiere que son problemas con el servicio ejecutándose en el puerto, pero estoy seguro de que eso esta bien y en ese puerto. Aquí está el fragmento de código que hace la petición http:

```
const httpOptions = {
    hostname: urlData[0],
    path: urlData[1],
    port: urlData[2],
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
};

http.request(httpOptions, res => {
    let data = "";
    res.on("data", d => data += d)
    res.on("end", () => console.log(data));
})
    .on("error", err => console.error(err))
    .end(jsonData);
```

Agradecería la respuesta, llevo algunos días tratando de encontrar solución sin resultados.

Comment: Y tienes el código del `servidor`? El problema que tú servidor no está escuchando por el puerto 3004 o no está activo. Quizá puedas usar. El `netstat -p TCP` y verifica si está en `LISTENiNG` el puerto 3004.

Comment: Chequea si tienes fierewall activo que pueda bloquear el puerto

Comment: Ya revise con el comando netstat y de hecho no me aparece, cosa curiosa porque en la terminal si me manda el mensaje de que se esta ejecutando la app, es diferente cuando se ejecuta con node? o porque con express si me imprime el mensaje pero no me aparece por el comando netstat?

PD: desactivar el firewall no funciono

Comment: Es igual para cualquier software que escuche un puerto TCP. Puede que esté ejecutando pero también puede que no esté escuchando por ese puerto. Chequea con netstat en el momento que está ejecutando y luego bajas el server y das otro netstat y fíjate si cambio algo con respecto al primero.

Comment: Nada amigo, no sirvió, aunque estoy pensando seriamente en hacer esa petición http con python en lugar de node, alguna recomendación? Saludos